# Calligraphy letter in \underset{}{}

Tags: equations, mathcal

I have tried using `\underset{}{}` to get the result on the picture. The result I had with the normal use ofI thought it is because of the equation block and `\mathcal{Q}`, but it turned out to be the `\underset`. The equation is within a `.tex` file which is included in latex preamble, and does not have

`\begin{document}`
`\end{document}` Can someone help?

[image]

EDIT:
I did try this:

```
\begin{equation}\label{4.14}
 \underset{\mathcal{Q} }{argmin} 
\end{equation}
```

and the result I got is the following: 
[image]
I found out that the problem is with `\underset` as when I do `\mathcal{Q}` in the equation block it shows the correct letter.

Comment: you haven't shown what you did, or what error you got. what "turned out to be the `\underset` " ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: even with the edit you have never explained what the problem is `\mathcal{Q}` works in underset just as it works in a subscript in the posted answer.

Comment: I thought it implies that the Q under argmax/argmin is not the calligraphic one I wanted. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Load `amsmath` package (if not yet) and define on preamble a new operator which takes limit below: `\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}` and then inside your math expression use it as `\[ x^* = \argmin_{x\in \mathcal{Q}} \phi(x) \]` for display or `$ x^* = \argmin\limits_{x\in \mathcal{Q}} \phi(x) $` for inline mode.

[image]

Comment: …with compliments to your crystal ball!

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti, were you going to do the same? Probably.

Comment: Great, thank you @Sigur! The first solution was the one I was needed!